# Database options for android?

Tags: android, sql-server-ce

I am a CS major and I just recently decided to start putting some of my java knowledge to use by learning how to program with Android. I have just been doing tutorials and reading some books on how to get started, but I would like to write an app and eventually release it to the app store. I have most of the ins and outs of the app figured out, but I'm not sure how to approach data storage. Part of my app will track shipping numbers and info, however, each shipment will have a pretty long list of fields (Name, ID, Address, Weight, Girth, ect.). The list in full approaches 10 items, if you include optional fields. Thats a lot of information to have a user fill out, especially if they have to do it on their phone (app is designed for small businesses, so lots of shipping for tracking). I would prefer not to have to build a sister website to hold this info for the user, so I guess my question would be, is there a service for mobile apps to use to push and pull info that a user could access through their computer? Or would it be better to use a file uploader and just format the info? I'm still an android novice, so I figured I need a little advice from the pros. Any and all advice would be appreciated, and if you know a database type service that is safe and reliable, that would help very much. Thank you!

Comment: You could try SQLite3 as a database.  It's popular because it's lightweight.

Comment: I would suggest TinyDB or SQLite3 as @duffymo suggested

Comment: Depends on how you are going to use your data , is it necessary to keep data online or would you like to store it on phone ?